# How do I catch ArgumentError invalid base64 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rescue

How do I catch this exception?

```
    begin
      data = Base64.strict_decode64(data) # decode data
      ...
    rescue ArgumentError => e
      logger.severe "Could not decrypt data: #{e}, #{data}"
```

#### Log

> ArgumentError (invalid base64):
>     config/application.rb:32:in `decrypt'

Comment: you are already catching the exception, you might need to be more explicit with your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that I modified config/application, which requires restarting the server. Which is odd, because the error page showed the updated source code and the line number pointing to `begin`!

I found I did not have access to `logger` either! This is the finished product:

```
    begin
      data = Base64.strict_decode64(data) # decode data
      ...
    rescue ArgumentError => e
      Rails.logger.warn "Could not decrypt data: #{e}, #{data}"
      text = ""
    end
```